# Получение темы на Next.js

Tags: javascript, nextjs

Как получить тему, которая установлена у человека в браузере. Попытался сам сделать, но данный код ниже работает только в React а тут ошибка с window

```
'use client'
import {useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState} from "react";

export const useTheme = () => {

        const idDarkTheme = window?.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
        const defaultTheme = idDarkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'

        const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem('app-theme') || defaultTheme)

        useLayoutEffect(() => {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
            localStorage.setItem('app-theme', theme)
        }, [theme]);

        return {theme, setTheme}
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, что `window` не `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Страницы в nextjs рендерятся на сервере, там недоступно браузерное api: `window`, `localStorage`

Гарантированно на клиенте выполняется все, что указано в `useEffect`:

```
export const useTheme = () => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light')

    useEffect(()=>{
        const idDarkTheme = window?.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
        const defaultTheme = idDarkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light'

        setTheme(localStorage.getItem('app-theme') || defaultTheme);
    },[]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
        localStorage.setItem('app-theme', theme);
    }, [theme]);

    return {theme, setTheme}
}
```

Comment: `Next.js` будет вечно ругаться на `useLayoutEffect` :(

Comment: @OliverPatterson, ну warning - не ошибка :)